# What does コミュニケーションがとれる mean?

Tags: definitions, set-phrases

I tried looking up what 「コミュニケーションがとれる」 means, but from the examples that I've seen, all I can understand is that it just means "to communicate". Is there something more to this phrase that I'm not seeing?

[These](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B&ref=sa) are the examples that I was referring to. Why isn't this just 「コミュニケーションができる」? What exactly is 「とる」 in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> コミュニケーションがとれる = to be able to communicate.
>   コミュニケーションをとる = to communicate.

In my experience, it is used a lot to speak about communication skills. So it's more than just being able to be heard and to hear.

You could say

> そのチームはコミュニケーションがとれている。

about a team where all members speak a lot to each others.

Comment: I don't understand how "a team where all members speak a lot to each others" is representative of having communication skills. Is it similar to "a team of members who communicate with each other well"?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to say that it's not pure physical communication like the phone line is working. It's more human level.